# mysql - selecting people born after a certain year

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table of employees which includes a column birth_day as well as PRIMARY KEY of emp_ID (employee ID).
There is also another table called Works_With with the employee emp_ID and total_sales by employee

What I want to do is to select the top 5 performing employees born after certain year, which is 1970.

How would I proceed..

I am thinking it was this but didn't work

```
SELECT total_sales
FROM works_with
WHERE employee.birth_day => '1970/MM/DD' LIMIT 5 DESC;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If your `birth_day` column holds a datetime, this should work:

```
SELECT employee.emp_ID, total_sales
FROM works_with
INNER JOIN employee
ON works_with.emp_ID = employee.emp_id
       AND year(employee.birth_day) >= 1970 
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: It's DATE in YYYY/MM/DD. Is INNER JOIN necessary to get this?

Comment: Since you are combining data from two tables, you need to join them, either explicit (with JOIN ... ON) or implicit (multiple tables in FROM ... WHERE). Afaik, implicit join syntax is discouraged. Either way, in your query above, the table employee is not present in the FROM clause, so you cannot use its columns in the WHERE clause.

Comment: What is `=>`? And note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: You are absolutely right. The first one is a typo, the second one I just copied from the original statement without thinking about it as I focused on the join. My bad, I'll edit it.